# How to install Eigen3 on the docker image created by 'cibuildwheel' in GitHub actions

Tags: python, c++, github-actions, eigen3, pybind11

I am currently developing a C++/Python package using `pybind11` for the Python bindings. This project is mixed: it has parts which are written in Python and other parts which are written in C++ and are compiled as an external module.

The project uses `cmake>1.7`. Roughly this is the directory structure of the project:

```
PythonProject
 -> python_sources
 -> include [cpp headers]
 -> src [cpp sources]
   --> module.cpp [pybind11 bindings declaration]
   --> cpp_sources [where the implementation of the headers goes]
```

The project also depends on Eigen3.

I have the project setup, so that when building the wheels the cpp module is compiled first and then the `*.so` (if macOS) is copied to `python_sources`.

In my machine (`macOS 11.2 with XCODE 12`) I can generate the wheels with

`python -m build` or `python -m build --sdist`(depending if I am only building source distributions)

This works well and I'm able to test the installation with `pip install -e ./`.

However, when setting up the CI with Github actions and `cibuildwheel` I am not able to install `libeigen3-dev` with `apt-get` in the docker (I set up the `CIBW_BEFORE_ALL_LINUX` and `CIBW_BEFORE_BUILD_LINUX` with this command).

Probably there is a very simple solution to this (apart from downloading the sources), but I unfortunately haven't been able to figure it out and would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `yum` instead of `apt-get`:

```
yum install eigen3-devel
```

as per OP esocrats' prior edit to the question.